# Can I fetch execution logs programmatically from AWS Step Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

My team has a Step function deployed in multiple geo distributed AWS accounts. We want to aggregate the execution logs from each of these step function instances into 1 data store. I was thinking of using a Lambda that would call the GetExecutionHistory API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_GetExecutionHistory.html, but the problem here becomes handling dedup - to avoid this we would have to only call the API once we know the step function is done, but this will be slow and that means there will be a big backlog of executions to process.

Rather, it would be great if there is a way to get notified of all execution events, INCLUDING start of execution and end of execution. That way, all events - hopefully associated with the event id itself, can be sent some queue. Then, I can have a reader lambda read from this and add to my backend store.

Any ideas/options around this?

Comment: You could use DynamoDB, where the partition key is event_id. In that case, the duplicate event will be overwritten with the newly added one. But I am not completely sure if that's what you are asking for.

Comment: Before dealing with the data storage, id like to know what options are available to query for or collect step function execution logs, and then pipe them to a data store. The solution should handle dedup case, which is why i would prefer an event notification based system

Comment: Not sure exactly what your requirements are from the aggregation of the execution logs. I would start with writing an event to *Event-bridge* at the end of the step functions and trigger a Lambda that will write the `GetExecution` response to OpenSearch.

Comment: @Guy so at a high level we want to track executions as well as do queries on them. So I would like to have not only start time/end time/status of the execution, but also success/failure of each step so we can tell when a step function stopped. To make it simple for now, I want to pipe execution log data - as granular as possible - to some data store. I think a notification system would work well here and am exploring the eventbridge solution now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Event bridge with.

{
"source": ["aws.states"]
}

[image]

You can have lambda as target of this event that will parse step function and save to S3 or where ever you want
This will work for every step changes change .

Comment: Hey just 1 clarification, when you specify aws.states, this works for each intermediate step in the step function as well right, not just the overall execution?

Comment: Yes it works in each intermediate steps .But be aware the more steps you have the more data you will have